# Bootstrap 4, remove white space next to dark column on the right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

So I had this problem for quite a while now, it has to do with the sidebar on the left because without it the white space on right side just dissapears, but I'm not sure where the problem is at, I tried looking up at other people suggestions, but nothing worked so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, thanks!

If I add `.container` class to nav container, white space moves to the left side next to sidebar

[image]

```css
/*
DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,         shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container-flex">
    <!-- navbar top-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
              <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
            <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
          <div class="col">
            <!--main page-->
            <p>Main Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
          <div class="col bg-dark">
            <!--Code Editor-->
            <p>Code Editor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sometimes margin is not counted as part of parent (by default), So, use  `overflow: auto;` on parent to count any child margin in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the class [`.justify-content-between`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content) to the `.row`:

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,         shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="container-flex">
  
    <!-- navbar top-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
      
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
              <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
              <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
            <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
          <div class="col">
            <!--main page-->
            <p>Main Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
          <div class="col bg-dark">
            <!--Code Editor-->
            <p>Code Editor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man, adding class next to the row class in div worked like a charm!